# Need help with linear ODE, indicial and recurrence.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble understanding something and I want to post what I have done so hopefully someone can catch where I have made a mistake.

The question asks; determine the indicial equation, recurrence relation and roots of the indicial equations and find the series solution $x \gt 0 $ corresponding to the larger root. It is to use series to solve for

$$2xy''+y'+xy=0$$

What I have done;

Noted that $x_o=0$ is a regular singular point.

Let $$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{r+n}$$
$$y'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(r+n)a_nx^{r+n-1}$$
$$y''=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(r+n)(r+n-1)a_nx^{r+n-2}$$

Then I subbed in to get

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2(r+n-1)(r+n)a_nx^{r+n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(r+n)a_nx^{r+n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{r+n+1}=0$$

So I noted that I can write the last sum as $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-2}x^{r+n-1}$$

Which suggested to me I strip out $a_o$ and $a_1$ terms and write the rest starting from index two, i.e.

for $n=0$ we have $$a_o[2(r-1)( r)+r]x^{r-1}$$ ie $2(r-1)( r)+r=0$ and for $n=1$ $$a_1[2r(r+1)+(r+1)]x^{r}$$ ie $2r(r+1)+(r+1)=0$

so that + $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}[2(r+n-1)(r+n)+(r+n)]a_n+a_{n-1}=0$$

So to me it is clear where my relation for $a_{n}$ will come from simply because the inside of the summation is equal to zero.

But here is the thing, which is my indicial equation? Is it the one corresponding to $a_0$ or is it the one corresponding to $a_1$?

The answer given is $r(2r-1)=0$ but I don't know how.

First off, if anyone can explain this that would be great, and second off is anyone can conform what I have been doing is correct?

I really hope someone can help, I am trying very hard to understand these as I have an exam coming up eventually and want to do my best.

Thank you all for time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you connect $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$. In the index shift you had that right, in the recursion equation (lose the sum sign) this changed.

Using the equation for degree $n=0$ and setting $a_1=0=a_{2m+1}$ or using the equation for degree $n=1$ and setting $a_0=0=a_{2m}$ results in the same solutions, since that index shift is compensated by the root values of $r$.

Comment: Thanks, so I will get the same indicial equation regardless of which I pick?

Comment: No, you will get identical solutions, but the roots of the indicial equations in the coefficients of $a_0$ and $a_1$ differ by 1.

Answer (score 0):

2(r-1)r+r reduces to the answer you are looking for. I dont see a problem with the indicial equation

Comment: So how do I know for a do I take to be the indicial eq?